# Is updating person data supported of Google People API v1?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

Using the following 
Windows 10 x64
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
Targeting Dot Net Framework 4.6
Installed Google.Apis.People.v1 via NuGet (It installed all its dependencies)

I am able to list the users contacts by calling
`PeopleService.People.Connections.List("people/me").Execute`
which returns `ListConnectionsResponse` 
now i can access the users contact by using the `ListConnectionsResponse.Connections` property

Now i want to update `Person.Photos`

I have searched on https://developers.google.com/people/ but haven't found anything regarding updating, my best guess is that, it's not yet supported.

Can you help me, by pointing in the right direction, and correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/) is read only like the Google+ API there is no way to update someone's photo programmatically.